# How to Attach an Object to a Posable Model?

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

My goal is to have hair move with the head.  I tried parenting them together and that allowed both the player and hair piece to move together in Object Mode, but Pose Mode still doesn't work with the hair.

First, let it be known I'm complete Blender beginner. I used to play around with it years ago to import models, pose them, take pictures, and that's it. Well I wanna start learning Blender properly so I figured I'd ask the pros.

Basically I downloaded a Minecraft player model which I put my own texture on, posed, and took pictures like normal. But my character in game has a 3D hair texture, so I took a cube, subdivided a bunch of times, and textured it properly. All's good and it looks pretty great. But any time I go into Pose Mode to pose the model, the hair model stays where it is and doesn't move with the head. I tried grouping the hair and head together but it would just screw up the polygons. Then I tried parenting them together and that allowed both the player and hair piece to move together in Object Mode, but Pose Mode still doesn't work with the hair. Anyone know how to get the two to stick together properly? I've included images below.

[image: in progress]

Creating and texturing the hair model

[image: good render]

The proper render

[image: Broken pose]

Non-conforming hair piece

Comment: Its good that you placed pictures in your question.  A suggestion. Place images of the parenting for example from the outliner window.  Parent Child relationship should be shown in some way.  Some of the pictures do not address the problem.   The reader needs to see your parent child relationship.

Comment: Did you parent the hair to the head or to the neck bone?  You should also see video tutorials on parenting.  When you are a little experienced in parent child relationship the operation should take about 33 seconds or less.  The head should be the parent .. the hair should be the child.

Comment: Placing two items in a collection, 2.8 terminology, does not mean they will move together.  Prior to 2.8 this was called a group. They are similar not identical.

Comment: I did a quick little bit of parenting research and took your advice and got it to work! First I was having issues getting the parent/child ordering correct and then got confused when I would parent it to the skeleton and it wouldn't work. Then I realized I could group it to a specific bone, so I picked the head bone and now the rotation works great! Unfortunately it isn't mapped to the squash/stretch feature the rig came with but I don't see myself using that anytime soon. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Now that you know more about Blender parent child‍‍‍... I am sure Blender will pose a new challenge for you ... it always does.